# Jenkins "Console Output" is virtually empty

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, console, jenkins, output

I have a fresh Jenkins install on Ubuntu

1. New Job -> Build multi-configuration project
2. Scroll down and click "Add build step" -> Execute shell and enter:

   ```
   echo hello
   ```
3. Run the job (it succeeds)
4. Look at the Console Output for the run:

   ```
   Started by user My Name
   Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/my_job/workspace
   Triggering default
   default completed with result SUCCESS
   Finished: SUCCESS
   ```

Follow the steps again, but with the Execute shell:

```
echo hello
thisshouldfail
```

and you get...

```
Started by user My Name
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/my_job/workspace
Triggering default
default completed with result FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Notice how nowhere do you see "hello" in the output. This goes for anything I might put in that Execute Shell. Any help?

Comment: Is there a verbose or debug mode you can set to get all the output? I get all the output on mine

Comment: I don't know. I poked around and even googled for it. I don't know anything about jenkins or java really, so I'm in the dark here.

Comment: A multi-configuration build is a very different beast then a regular build. Unless you got reasons for using a multi-configuration build, you should try a regular "freestyle" build first. Everything you wrote should work just as expected in freestyle build

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When running a *Multi-Configuration* project, the log you see is of the **Manager-job**,
and it only shows you the summary of the complete run, which is, basically:
"I ran all your jobs, and all went OK" (`Finished: SUCCESS`)
or
"I ran all your jobs, and at least one of them failed" (`Finished: FAILURE`)

It cannot give you a single log of all the runs, because they ran multiple times
(on different slaves and/or different configurations).

To see the log of each run, click each red (or blue) "ball" in the matrix -
each represents a single instance of that Multi-Configuration build.

Comment: Thanks Gonen! Not sure what the purpose is of a multi-config project, unless it's to confuse people and make them post this question on SO. Slav's comment to the OP above pretty much nailed it.

Comment: Well, I think the idea is nice, but the UI can be improved... Surely it does not fit the common build flow.